# Why flutter's Future function runs several times?

Tags: flutter, asynchronous, dart, future

I have this code

```
  _CurrentDayPageState() {
    getSchedule().then((s) => setState(() {
      _todaySchedule = s;
    }));
  }

  ...

  Future<List<Map<String, dynamic>>> getSchedule() async {

    DateTime now = new DateTime.now();
    List<String> todayBorders = [DatabaseHelper.getStartOfTheDay(now), DatabaseHelper.getEndOfTheDay(now)];

    print(todayBorders);

    List<Map<String, dynamic>> schedule = await dbHelper.queryRowsSql("SELECT * FROM ${tableSchedule} WHERE "
        "Datetime(${columnDateTime}) BETWEEN Datetime('${todayBorders[0]}') AND Datetime('${todayBorders[1]}')");

    print("get schedule gone");

    return schedule;
  }
```

And have this output:

```
I/flutter (15242): [2020-06-15 00:00:00, 2020-06-15 23:59:59]
I/flutter (15242): [2020-06-15 00:00:00, 2020-06-15 23:59:59]
I/flutter (15242): [2020-06-15 00:00:00, 2020-06-15 23:59:59]
I/flutter (15242): get schedule gone
I/flutter (15242): get schedule gone
I/flutter (15242): get schedule gone
```

If I use FutureBuilder I have same triple function call. Is there my fault or I forget about something? Thank you for feedback!

**SOLVED**
It's was because of bottomNavigationBar in which the page is located rebuilds himself as many times as childs it have.

Comment: Unless that `setState` call is causing it to run more times (you can check this with a debugger or by removing the `setState` call), you will need to provide more code because nothing there pops out as wrong.

Comment: @GregoryConrad for the reply! Commented all setStates, nothing has changed. But I discovered a new interesting thing: this page exists on the stack and bottomNavigationBar is called. Therefore, when I reduced the number of bottomNavigationBar pages by one, I received only 2 function calls (exactly as many as the pages).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its because probably the function is called on state build. something in your widget tree is rebuilding the State thus calling the function again

Comment: Thanks for the reply! As I said to @GregoryConrad, I discovered a new interesting thing: this page exists on the stack and bottomNavigationBar is called. Therefore, when I reduced the number of bottomNavigationBar pages by one, I received only 2 function calls (exactly as many as the pages).

Comment: As per my knowledge botNav rebuilds it self the same amount of times it has childrens.

Comment: So if thats the case it mean the ui rebuids each time the botNav is loading a child.

Comment: ok, it's clear now, thank you very much! I will move all my data manipulations to highest app point.